# MySQL - cannot log in to MySQL on Lion OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, terminal, passwords, osx-lion

I have installed a Rails app with MySQL database on Lion OS X.
In the **config/database.yml** for database is set up user (root) + password.

When I try to log in into MySQL from terminal: **mysql -uroot** or **mysql -u root**, I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I even tried to set up a new password, but I got again the same error message.
How can I log in from terminal to MySQL and browse tables in databases?

Thanks

Comment: Oh, that's the parameter

Comment: Yeah, go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) for more clarification